# laravel 5.5 middleware auth keeps redirecting home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to login but it keeps redirecting me back to the home page, in laravel 5.2 i wouldn't have this problem.

Thanks in advance, there seem to be no tutorials about this change.

web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard',
    'middleware' => 'auth'


]);
```

and I traced it back to this.

kernal.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Usercontroller.php

```
   public function userLogin(Request $request)
    {

        $remember = $request->input['remember_me'];

        if(Auth::attempt(['username'=> $request['username'], 'password' => $request['password']], $remember )){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }

   public function getDashboard()
    {
        $cookie = cookie('saw-dashboard', true, 15);
        $users = User::all();
        $user = new User();

        return view('dashboard', array('user'=> Auth::user()), compact('users'))->withCookie($cookie);
    }

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I checked my network console and it's a 302 not found not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam my login works fine without the middleware do you want to see the login code ?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam check it now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with middleware with like this:

> **middleware('auth:api');**

Comment: i tried that and now it just redirects back to the login page.

Comment: its on my web.php file

Comment: then use auth:web

Comment: still didn't work it just redirects back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Change route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@getDashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

[Registering Middleware in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: that a basic route. Do you have custom authController ??

Comment: 302 not found, it just keep redirecting to login page let me clear my cookies

Comment: run this too `php artisan route:clear ;php artisan cache:clear; composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Hey make sure login controller is outside the auth middleware

Comment: post the route on `userLogin` function

Comment: @ohh  i see what you mean, let me do that.

Comment: yeah still didn't work i tried this

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

 Route::post('/auth/login','UserController@userLogin')->name('login');

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@getDashboard')->name('dashboard');
});`

Comment: this should be out side the auth middle `Route::post('/auth/login','UserController@userLogin')->name‌​('login');`

Comment: just tried still didn't work, just keeps redirecting to login page